# a question on the lamplighter group

Tags: group-theory

I was reading some material on the lamplighter group and I wanted to know the following: Is the lamplighter group abelian?

Comment: Perhaps the standard [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group) of the lamplighter group would help.

Comment: I'm new to this so I don't understand

Comment: The lamplighter group can be thought of as abstract group, but that's not convenient as the presentation is not pleasant.  Much better to think of it as a matrix group, as discussed in that wiki article.  It should be easy for you to check whether or not that matrix group is abelian.

Comment: so we check the group axioms?

Comment: Not following.  If you have no idea how to check if a group is abelian or not, the lamplighter group is a very poor place to start.  Try simpler examples first.

Comment: Anyway the answer to your question is no.

Comment: So we have to check if it is commutative since the lamplighter is already a group?

Comment: Walking two steps to the right and then turning on the lamp is different from turning on the lamp and then walking two steps to the right.

Comment: I'd prefer an example so I can see what's going on

Comment: @lulu I prefer to think of it as a wreath product.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Me too, but I figured the OP wouldn't know what that meant.

Answer (score 4):

It's finitely generated, so all you need to do is check whether the generators commute.

Taking the presentation in Wikipedia, a toggle followed by a move does not give the same result as a move followed by a toggle.

Comment: ok so its not abelian, thanks